# how to use variable in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android

I just started learning programming at the android and I have a problem with using variable at `onSaveInstanceState`. This is my code:

```
int resultCode;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        int resultCode = savedInstanceState.getInt("resultCode");
    } 

    Button btnOpenWithResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpenWithResult);
    btnOpenWithResult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(flashlight.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (resultCode) {
    case 1:   
         /** option 1  */            
        break;
    case 2:
         /** option 2 */
        break;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("resultCode", resultCode);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I want to save the variable `resultCode` using `onSaveInstanceState` and after the resumption of activity once again to use it ...

(sorry for my level of English)

Comment: Be more specific, what exactly is your problem? Did you tried to assign value to resultCode.

Comment: My problem is save state of variable resultCode (switch) to onSaveInstanceState. When I write: savedInstanceState.putInt("resultCode", resultCode); and after that try use: int resultCode = savedInstanceState.getInt("resultCode"); then variable resultCode it's empty

Comment: you should explore other options for permanent storage of data in memory. For instance, why not declare the variable as static or even on a static class apart?

Answer (score 6):

Cyren... 1) I see no reason to call super.onRestoreInstanceState in onCreate. It WOULD make sense to make that call in the method

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle saved) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(saved);
```

2) The declaration:

```
   int resultCode = savedInstanceState.getInt("resultCode");
```

is "hiding" the variable:

```
int resultCode;
```

declared earlier. So there are two version of the variable resultCode with different scopes. Perhaps you mean to code:

```
int resultCode;

stuff here

    resultCode = savedInstanceState.getInt("resultCode");
```

Hope that helps,
JAL