# how do I keep Spinner selected item after restart or resume application

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have to keep `Spinner` selected item remain same, after `onRestart()` or `onResume()` the application. `Spinner` items are getting populated from sqlite database using `ArrayAdapter`. so guide me how do I achieve this.

```
String myString = (String) myspinner.getSelectedItem();` //the value you want the position for
    ` @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdap = (ArrayAdapter<String>) myspinner.getAdapter(); //cast to an ArrayAdapter
    int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(myString);
    //set the default according to value
    myspinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Comment: Edit your question and format it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store last selected position into `share-Preference or in database` and when app restart then pass that appropriate stored position to your spinner, and keep updating SP while changing position into spinner.

Store position:

```
SharedPreferences SP;
SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SP.edit().putInt("last index", spin.getSelectedItemPosition()).commit();
```

Retrieve and set to spinner:

```
 SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
     if(SP!=null){
             int pos = SP.getInt("last index", 0);

             spin.setSelection(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save the position of spinner in onSaveInstanceState() and retrive the spinner position
from onRestoreInstanceState (). you can use a common global variable for update the spinner
position.

and use this variable in onResume() method .
hope that it will work

[check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701275/how-to-use-variable-in-onsaveinstancestate)